# Ajax is not supporting IE 9

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I'm having this problem with my AJAX, where it's not working in IE 9,7 but it is working fine with Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari,chrome .So I don't see why it would be wrong.Here i put my complete code.Can anyone help me out?

```
<html>
<head>
<IMG src="karvy.jpg" ALT="image">
<LINK href="text1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script language="JavaScript" src="ts_picker.js"></script>
<script>
    function fetch_javaScript(fund, agent, fromDate, toDate) {
        var ajaxRequest; // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { //Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
            ajaxRequest = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0");
            } catch (e) {
            }
            try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
            } catch (e) {
            }
            try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
            }
            throw new Error("This browser does not support XMLHttpRequest.");
        }
        // Create a function that will receive data
        // sent from the server and will update
        // div section in the same page.

        function handler() {
            if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("ajaxDiv").innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
            }
        }

        function get_selected_data(o) {
            var selectedOptions = [];
            for ( var i = 0; i < o.options.length; i++) {
                if (o.options[i].selected) {
                    selectedOptions.push('"' + o.options[i].value + '"');
                }
            }
            if (selectedOptions.length) {
                return '[]=[' + selectedOptions.join(',') + ']';
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }

        // var fund = document.getElementById('fund').value;
        // var agent = document.getElementById('agent').value;
        var fromDate = document.getElementById('fromDate').value;
        var toDate = document.getElementById('toDate').value;
        var queryString = "?fund="
                + get_selected_data(document.getElementById('fund'));
        queryString += "&agent="
                + get_selected_data(document.getElementById('agent'));
        queryString += "&fromDate=" + fromDate;
        queryString += "&toDate=" + toDate;

        if (ajaxRequest != null) {
            ajaxRequest.open("GET", "final_ajax.pl" + queryString, true);
            ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = handler;
            //console.log(queryObj.fund);
            ajaxRequest.send(null);
        } else {
            window.console.log("AJAX (XMLHTTP) not supported.");
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" name="tstest">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">
                        <h1>MFS CALL RECORDINGS</h1>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h2>Funds</h2>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="Funds" id=fund multiple>
                        <option value="Select">Select</option>
                        <option value="PMF">Principal</option>
                        <option value="PRAMERICA">Pramerica</option>
                        <option value="JM">JM</option>
                        <option value="DHL">DHL</option>
                        <option value="EMF">Edelweiss MF</option>
                        <option value="MORGAN">Morgan</option>
                        <option value="DAIWA">Daiwa</option>
                        <option value="TAURUS">Taurus</option>
                        <option value="AXIS">AXIS</option>
                        <option value="BPMF">BPMF</option>
                        <option value="PLMF">Peerless MF</option>
                        <option value="LIC NOMURA">LIC NOMURA</option>
                        <option value="PNB">PNB</option>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h2>Agents</h2>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="Agents" id="agent" multiple>
                        <option value="Select">Select</option>
                        <option value="Gyanesh">Gyanesh</option>
                        <option value="Satish">Satish</option>
                        <option value="Sailesh">Sailesh</option>
                        <option value="ArchanaMuluguru">Archana</option>
                        <option value="Santosh">Santosh</option>
                        <option value="Afreen">Afreen</option>
                        <option value="Salman">Salman</option>
                        <option value="Balaji">Balaji</option>
                        <option value="Priyanka">Priyanka</option>
                        <option value="KavithaGolla">Kavitha</option>
                        <option value="Rajvardhan">Rajvardhan</option>
                        <option value="Srinivasp">Srinivasp</option>
                        <option value="Surekha">Surekha</option>
                        <option value="Mazhar">Mazhar</option>
                        <option value="Pneeraja">Pneeraja</option>
                        <option value="Samiullah">Samiullah</option>
                        <option value="Nisar">Nisar</option>
                        <option value="Kareem">Kareem</option>
                        <option value="Shesherao">Shesherao</option>
                        <option value="KuttiSirisha">KuttiSirisha</option>
                        <option value="Sunitha">Sunitha</option>
                        <option value="Pavanir">Pavanir</option>
                        <option value="Divyav">Divyav</option>
                        <option value="Leela">Leela</option>
                        <option value="Avinash">Avinash</option>
                        <option value="BHARATI">Bharati</option>
                        <option value="Anil">Anil</option>
                        <option value="Sravan">Sravan</option>
                        <option value="Sudhakar">Sudhakar</option>
                        <option value="Madan">Madan</option>
                        <option value="Raghu">Raghu</option>
                        <option value="Rahul">Rahul</option>
                        <option value="Srinivas B">Srinivas B</option>
                        <option value="Akhilesh">Akhilesh</option>

                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>

                    <h2>From Date</h2>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="Text" name="timestamp" id="fromDate" value="">
                    <a href="javascript:show_calendar('document.tstest.timestamp', document.tstest.timestamp.value);">
                        <img src="cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Click Here to Pick up the timestamp">
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h2>To Date</h2>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="Text" name="timestamp1" id="toDate" value="">
                    <a href="javascript:show_calendar('document.tstest.timestamp1', document.tstest.timestamp1.value);">
                        <img src="cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Click Here to Pick up the timestamp">
                    </a>
                    <input type="Button" id="val" value="Submit" align="middle" method="GET" onclick="fetch_javaScript()" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tfoot>
                <tr align="center">


                </tr>

            </tfoot>
        </table>

    </form>
    <div id='ajaxDiv'>Your Result Will Display Here</div>
<body style="background-color: white;">

</body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use jquery ajax, this is headache now. jquery ajax workd in all latest browsers.

Comment: hit f12 and check if there are any javascript errors in ie that could help point to the problem

Comment: A JSFiddle of only the relevant code, or a stripped down example would help us - you might even answer your own question in doing so.

Comment: you're in compatibility mode so IE9 is pretending to be IE7, add a `DOCTYPE` to bring up the standards compatible apis

Comment: Get rid of the ActiveX stuff -- it's unnecessary. You only need that if you're supporting IE6 or earlier. (you're not supporting IE6, right?)

Comment: @Mgetz - you're right that he needs a doctype. You're wrong about what it does; it's worse than that -- missing the doctype actually flips you into Quirks mode, which is an IE5-compatible mode.

Comment: @Spudley ah its been awhile since I've even considered quirks mode so I didn't think it went that far back

Comment: Anyway, I think you've probably nailed the issue; you should post it as an answer.

Comment: Don't worry about < IE 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue stems from the lack of a `DOCTYPE` in your page in IE this drops the page to IE5 compatibility mode e.g. quirks mode. to fix it just add a `DOCTYPE` like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<IMG src="karvy.jpg" ALT="image">
<LINK href="text1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script language="JavaScript" src="ts_picker.js"></script>
```

This will put you in standards mode which will act like a modern browser.